# O que significa "modificada pela Comunidade"?

Tags: suporte

Eu sei que "Comunidade" é um usuário especial, ou algo assim.

De vez em quando vemos na página inicial perguntas que foram "modificadas pela Comunidade":

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao entrar nada aconteceu: pergunta, respostas, tags, tudo ficou intacto. Então porque aquilo foi parar na sessão "ativos"?

Parece que normalmente são perguntas que ficaram inativas por muito tempo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Olhando no [perfil da Comunidade ♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) podemos ver um pouco do que ele faz:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preste atenção no primeiro bullet que diz:

> - Dar uma mexida em perguntas antigas sem resposta, pra elas receberem um pouco de atenção

E a imagem que você anexou na sua pergunta mostra o resultado dessa ação.

Existem algumas condições que devem ser satisfeitas para tornar a pergunta elegível a tomar uma "mexida" da Comunidade ♦, pode conferir quais são elas aqui: [O que acontece com perguntas "eternas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4269/3117)

Comment: Os utilizadores locked por moderadores também aparecem como "comunidade" se eles modificarem o post.