# Questões editadas pela "Comunidade♦" não mostram aonde foi a edição?

Tags: suporte, edição

As vezes aparece edições feitas pela *Comunidade♦*, como nesta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao acessar as questões e respostas, não vejo nenhuma alteração perceptível e abaixo das publicações *não* aparece a informação de *"Editado 00/00 às 00:00"* e o perfil da *Comunidade♦*, só aparecem edições mais antigas (se houver).

Eu tenho pouco pontos para ver as tais edições e saber o que foi modificado?

Não sei se isto é certo, mas a resposta em *[O que significa “modificada pela Comunidade”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1954/3635)* não é clara, ou informativa o suficiente, com o perdão da palavra, me parece apenas um teoria.

> Nota: fiz exatamente o que é solicitado: Se essas **respostas** não abordarem completamente sua pergunta, edite esta pergunta para explicar de que forma ela difere da pergunta ou faça uma nova pergunta.
>
> Note que está escrito resposta e não pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, por favor reabrir, se eu estiver na abordagem correta do USO da comunidade (Se essas respostas não abordarem completamente sua pergunta). Grato.

Comment: Guilherme, mais tarde eu posto outra resposta lá ok? Mas a resposta do Math está correta, é a maneira que o sistema tem para chamar atenção para perguntas que ele considera esquecidas. Na verdade não há edição nenhuma, é só um artifício do sistema.

Comment: Posso tentar melhorar a resposta lá, mas basicamente é isso, a comunidade diz que editou a pergunta para que ela volte pro topo das perguntas ativas e receba mais atenção, mas de fato ela não exatamente modificou algo, a não ser a data da última atividade. Ainda ficou alguma duvida?

Comment: Obrigado mesmo @Math pelo retorno, mas nunca disse que sua resposta faltava algo, só não estava certo sobre as informações, só pensei que fosse algo teórico, mas não a desmereço. Obrigado pelo retorno, sim parece que a sua resposta está certa mesmo, obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Certo, mas supondo que eu quisesse responder sua pergunta agora, o que você gostaria de saber que ainda não foi dito lá? É se existe algum privilégio que você não tem que não lhe permite ver a modificação? É isso? Só quero entender pois ainda não ficou claro pra mim, não estou ofendido não :)

Comment: Sim, imaginei que fosse algo assim mesmo, questão de privilégios, mas pelo que vejo devo estar enganado.