# O que acontece com perguntas "eternas"?

Tags: debate

Hoje notei essa pergunta [Configurando jsTree para AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33428/configurando-jstree-para-ajax) que foi "editada" pelo usuário [Comunidade ♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade). Só que aparentemente o AP foi excluído ou foi banido, não sei ao certo, e a pergunta ficou sem resposta marcada como correta. Por esses motivos acredito que a pergunta ficará rodando na página *Principais perguntas* eternamente.

Existe algo a se fazer a respeito desse tipo de pergunta? Ou elas entram em um *loop* infinito e nada pode ser feito?

Comment: user7261 era o Andrey, ele solicitou a exclusão da conta por algum motivo

Comment: Enquanto existir o StackOverflow, tecnicamente todas as perguntas são eternas hahaha.

Answer (score 17):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/229289) no Meta StackExchange, todas as seguintes condições devem ser satisfeitas para tornar uma pergunta elegível a levar um *bump* da Comunidade ♦:

- Tópico com pelo menos 30 dias de inatividade;
- Pergunta com pontuação de 0 ou mais;
- Ao menos uma resposta com pontuação de exatamente zero;
- Nenhuma resposta com pontuação positiva;
- Nenhuma resposta aceita; e
- A pergunta não estar bloqueada ou fechada.

Portanto, para evitar o loop eterno não é necessária alguma ação por parte do autor da pergunta (que já não está mais entre nós), basta que ao menos uma das condições acima não seja satisfeita.

Se o *bump* dessa pergunta estiver te incomodando demais pense em qual das condições acima você quer atrapalhar e siga em frente =) As possibilidades são votar a favor ou contra a pergunta ou a resposta, votar para fechar a pergunta ou colocar sua própria resposta merecedora de um voto positivo. Apenas lembre-se de não usar seus poderes de votos de forma leviana e causar injustiças a quem quer que seja. Em outras palavras, se não domina o assunto, é melhor deixar o *bump* rolar para que não se encerre prematuramente as chances do tópico ter um desfecho apropriado.

Comment: Não creio que realizar alguma ação diretamente na "discussão" da pergunta seria uma solução. Como o SOpt é um site comunitário, eu posso ajudar a moderar uma questão sem necessariamente dominar o assunto da mesma, então realizar um _downvote_, _upvote_, _flood_ e etc... não seria uma boa forma de moderar tal questão, tendo em mente que eu posso não ter conhecimento para realizar algo produtivo à questão para realizar tais ações... Mais pessoas poderiam discutir a questão... :/

Comment: Se você não domina o assunto realmente é difícil tomar uma ação sem que acabe causando alguma injustiça, nesse caso é melhor deixar como está. (Acho que meu conselho foi falho, vou tentar reformulá-lo)

Comment: +1 pelo último parágrafo e pelo comentário.

Comment: O problema é que a pergunta não terá uma resposta aceita.

Comment: @Patrick isso não terá como evitar mesmo. Sugiro que leia [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/3117) e [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4097/3117)