# Como lidar com a falta de feedback constante?

Tags: debate, comportamento, usuarios

**Situação:**

O usuário faz uma pergunta, e você, como sabe responder, vai lá e responde. O autor da pergunta não lhe dá nenhum *feedback*. Você, portanto, não sabe se a sua solução foi de todo útil e, na minha opinião, isso gera dois problemas:

1. Nenhuma discussão produtiva pode surgir da pergunta, e
2. ninguém ganha pontos de internet.

Como a máxima **a sua dúvida pode ser a dúvida de outro** pra mim é válida, acredito que a falta de *feedback* é extremamente prejudicial para a comunidade como um todo, pois a pergunta simplesmente fica lá, esquecida, como se impossível fosse respondê-la. Mas tudo bem, isso acontece com uma única pergunta, fazer o quê? A vida é dura, mas segue em frente.

Eis que o mesmo usuário vem e faz outra pergunta, e a mesma situação ocorre. E outra vez, e outra... e o número de perguntas "não respondidas" feitas por tal usuário aumenta.

Notei essa ocorrência em alguns usuários em algumas tags que sigo com frequência, e também em outras que das quais não sou um visitador frequente. Esse tipo de comportamento me leva a, literalmente, ter preguiça de responder determinado usuário porquê sei que a discussão não será frutífera.

[Essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1428/23051) (com a qual eu concordo) mostra uma atitude bacana e resiliente para lidar com a ocorrência do problema em *uma* pergunta. [Essa discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/o-que-acontece-com-perguntas-eternas?cb=1) trás uma série de opiniões sobre perguntas que, por diferentes motivos, são esquecidas no limbo. [Essa outra resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4171/23051), do interminável Cigano, trata a questão geral da falta (ou não) de votos na comunidade como um todo. Todos esses tópicos tratam de uma situação geral, mas meu questionamento se direciona a quando esse tipo de comportamento ocorre com **um usuário específico**.

Como orientar **este** usuário hipotético? Devemos contactá-lo e orientá-lo a fornecer o seu *feedback*, seja ele qual for? [Essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1427/23051) sugere orientar o usuário a dar uma conferida na central de ajuda, pra entender o funcionamento da comunidade como um todo. Mas e quando você já analisou esse usuário, e concluí que ele **sabe sim** quais são as regras do jogo?

Só eu tive esse pensamento? Mais alguém tem preguiça de responder algumas perguntas (nada louvável, eu sei), simplesmente por saber que a discussão não vai pra lugar nenhum? Ou eu estou viajando completamente?

Comment: Tem mais alguém.

Comment: como diria um grande amigo meu, you never drink alone

Comment: De cada 100 emails que escrevo, tenho resposta de 2. A proporção no Stack é mais ou menos a mesma. Quando marcam a resposta como correta é tipo "wow, feedback!".

Comment: Relacionado: [Usuário ignorando orientações do uso correto do site e insiste em fazer o errado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4067/3117)

Comment: @Math a situação é bem parecida com essa!

Comment: Poisé, naquele caso pelo menos o cara comentava, aqui parece que nem isso acontece. A parte em comum é que o usuário acaba não usando a ferramenta do jeito que deveria para manter as demais pessoas interessadas em responder. O resumo daquele outro tópico é que o usuário não teve _conserto_.

Comment: É, no meu caso, o usuário pergunta E responde, mas nunca responde às respostas que são dadas a ele

Comment: Caio, desencana, a gente responde pra nós mesmos e pra visitantes futuros, se o autor da pergunta participa disso, fantástico, se não, azar...

Comment: Eu achava que o problema era os usuários novatos não fazerem o *tour*, mas ao ler aquela página recentemente percebi que lá explica somente como funciona o sistema, não diz que a participação e o feedback é importante. Acho que alguns usuários deixam de dar feedback por não saberem como fazer isso, não por maldade. Muitos frequentam fóruns e entram de gaiato no SOpt porque algum link do Google os trouxe aqui. O funcionamento de uma plataforma de fórum para o StackOverflow é grande, então acho que resta instruí-los a usar esse "mundo diferente", basta ter um pouco de paciência. (:

Comment: Acho que esse problema é exacerbado pela falta de votos, que já foi discutida várias vezes. No SOen também existem usuários assim, mas a comunidade é maior, mais madura, etc, e respostas boas sempre tem pelo menos alguns votos. A falta do feedback do AP é menos sentida, pois há um maior feedback da comunidade. Por exemplo, minha 3ª pergunta com mais votos (apenas 8) não recebeu feedback, mas a comunidade me mostrou que foi uma boa resposta, e, no caso, a melhor, pois as outras respostas tem apenas +1 e -1 voto.

Comment: Cada dia, o que me impressiona mais é "epa, olha só, *feedback!!!*... Não-feedback virou *default*.

Comment: @brasofilo disse tudo. pelo menos um "cara, não fale asneira, volte pro caminhão daonde você caiu" já seria alguma coisa, mas ultimamente nem isso

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Curto muito quando, meses depois, aparece um +1 ou um comentário agradecendo ou pedindo mais info. É aí quando me dou conta de que o autor original não é realmente importante. E não é só novato, tá cheio de usuário frequente que não diz nada, não vota nem marca resposta como correta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infelizmente não há nada que possa *forçar* alguém a aceitar ou comentar nas respostas... Nem mesmo a dar upvote. O máximo que nós, como comunidade, podemos fazer é instruir o melhor possível e esperar o melhor.

A [resposta do @utluiz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1428/12) descreve o caminho que considero ter mais chance de sucesso:

> 1. Não pressione o OP
> 2. Analise o perfil para inferir se ele já sabe usar o sistema (embora em alguns casos ele possa simplesmente esquecer de aceitar a resposta)
> 3. Espere
> 4. Espere
> 5. Espere
> 6. Adicione um comentário dizendo que se o problema foi resolvido ou a dúvida sanada, que por favor escolha a resposta que ele considera mais adequada, obviamente indicando a página da central de ajuda.

É preciso sempre manter em mente que o site vai sempre atrair pessoas que nunca usaram o SO original. Esse é um dos motivos dele existir. Então é normal que tenhamos um grande influxo de novatos que não estão habituados às regras e costumes do site.

Tudo que podemos fazer é instruir e ajudar o máximo possível todos que chegam, para que eles um dia possam nos ajudar a instruir e guiar ainda mais pessoas. Não é fácil e nem tem garantia de sucesso, mas é a melhor maneira de conscientizar todos que venham a participar do site.

Além disso, o @brasofilo [comentou algo muito importante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4346/como-lidar-com-a-falta-de-feedback-constante#comment13532_4346):

> Curto muito quando, meses depois, aparece um +1 ou um comentário agradecendo ou pedindo mais info. É aí quando me dou conta de que o autor original não é realmente importante. [...]

Faz muito bem sempre lembrar que tudo no site - perguntas e respostas - não são uma interação apenas entre duas pessoas. E elas não servem apenas naquele momento.

É claro que dá muito mais prazer quando você sabe que conseguiu ajudar alguém que precisava *agora*, e você recebe um retorno sobre o que fez. É assim que devia ser sempre. Mas falhando isso, sempre lembre que a pergunta não pertence apenas ao AP, mas sim a todo mundo que tiver o mesmo problema no futuro. E sua resposta não serve apenas para o AP, mas sim a qualquer um que venha precisar de ajuda.

O upvote meses depois é o melhor de todos! `:)`