# Perguntas antigas só podem ser encontradas pela busca?

Tags: suporte

Eu pesquisei e encontrei nada a respeito.

Gostaria de saber se as perguntas mais antigas só podem ser encontradas pela busca ou se quando faço alguma alteração ela vai pra página inicial novamente?

O que me levou a esse questionamento e que estou impedido de fazer comentários, talvez porque as perguntas que fiz não tiveram respostas ([essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152616/impress%c3%a3o-de-gr%c3%a1fico-teechat-no-delphi-xe5) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201288/aplicar-estilo-em-texto-de-um-richedit-no-delphi)) e também por uma resposta minha ter sido convertida em comentário e outra pergunta ter recebido um voto negativo (já foram removidas por mim). Por isso a única forma que encontrei, lendo algumas perguntas aqui no meta, era que minhas perguntas recebessem respostas ou votos, dessa forma o veto seria removido.

Só que eu não sei se minhas perguntas ainda podem ser encotradas por outros meios que não seja a busca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz alguma alteração na pergunta, ela volta automaticamente para a página inicial. Não só você; qualquer outro usuário que possua reputação suficiente pode editá-la e, da mesma maneira, a pergunta voltaria à página inicial.

Se a pergunta ficar *esquecida*, sem nenhuma atividade, o próprio sistema se encarrega de levá-la para a página inicial até que receba a devida atenção, seja algum usuário respondendo, seja a pergunta fechada quando necessário.

Mais sobre como esta segunda situação funciona você encontra em [O que acontece com perguntas “eternas”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/o-que-acontece-com-perguntas-eternas)

- Tópico com pelo menos 30 dias de inatividade;
- Pergunta com pontuação de 0 ou mais;
- Ao menos uma resposta com pontuação de exatamente zero;
- Nenhuma resposta com pontuação positiva;
- Nenhuma resposta aceita; e
- A pergunta não estar bloqueada ou fechada.

Nos seus dois casos, cedo ou tarde elas voltariam para a página inicial, até obter pelo menos uma resposta com votos positivos.

Comment: Valeu amigo!
Isso é muito bom pois as chances da pergunta ser respondida aumenta.
Bem interessante a forma como o SO funciona.

Comment: Aliás, se você tiver reputação suficiente, pode oferecer uma recompensa pela resposta. Desta forma ela fica em destaque na página inicial. Adicionarei isso a resposta assim que possível.

Comment: Infelizmente estou sem reputação até para comentar e para responder.
Postei uma mesma pergunta no **SOpt** e **SOen**. No **SOen** disseram que era uma boa pergunta, já no **SOpt** me negativaram. rs

Comment: Acontece. Aqui temos um padrão bem mais definido, visto que o número de usuários é bem menor. Não que lá seja bagunçado, mas o padrão não é tão bem definido. Não cheguei a analisar sua pergunta, então não estou afirmando que ela é ruim, mas se foi negativada, talvez tenha algo a melhorar.